# How to re install vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have some problem while debugging Flutter.

```
    FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
Not Found
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1392:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1259:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:924:22)
#3      _parseJson  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:29:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert  (dart:convert/json.dart:493:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode  (dart:convert/json.dart:151:41)
#6      jsonDecode  (dart:convert/json.dart:94:10)
```

there are some people who have the same problem, and they re-install vs code and it works. They said the error was related to the package.json file. How do I reinstall vs code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't guarantee these will solve your problem as I lack the full depth of context, but these should point you in the right direction based on what you mentioned.

***It could be a problem with your Extension for Dart in vs-code***, not vs-code itself. Try Reinstalling the plugin first and making sure you have the most recent version...

*Alternatively* **it may be a problem with your packages in your flutter project** because **flutter itself cannot understand what's been put in the json file**, try manually updating the package.json for your project (looking for any weird syntax and such) or finding an automated way to do it (for example with Node.js you can run npm-update)

*Alternatively* ***It may be a problem with flutter itself*** If the package.json file is fine and dandy, then Flutter is broken because it's not properly reading in the JSON file (it could be a bug but I'd say that's unlikely). In this case, reinstall flutter for this project and see what happens

**Uninstalling Vs-Code (Windows)**

1. press the **HomeButton + R** at the same time
2. **type in appwiz.cpl** to get to the control panel window for uninstalling software
3. **search for vs code** or search code in the search bar. **Right-Click and click uninstall**

Answer (score 0):

It pretty straight forward, Go to control panel and select uninstall a programme, search vs code and uninstall it. This will remove the software but not the saved files and usage data.

In order to do that follow :

1. Press Windows+r
2. Type %appdata%\local\Programs
3. Go to Microsoft VS Code and permanently delete this file
4. ----------Done-----------
5. Now install again.

Reinstall vs code.

Comment: C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions is this also deleted ??

Comment: Yes, you can always re-install the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted VS and extensions and done lots of other stuff listed as BrendanLester here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32841

Has the OP solved this yet?